# Login popup like digg or twitter

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am looking for jquery plugin popup like digg or twitter login.

Which jquery plugin can achieve this?

I should be able to add forms and including ajax support.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pretty much any modalbox plugin to achieve a similar effect. I like [simplemodal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) because of how easily it can be customized.

Answer (score 2):

[jquery ui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) is probably worth checking out. And if you are working much with AJAX forms [jquery form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) is a must have.

Comment: jquery ui is too big for my need.

Comment: @user622378, you have the possibility to [build it yourself](http://jqueryui.com/download) and take only what you need which in your case is `Dialog`. So put a check there and you are ready to roll.

Answer (score 0):

I really like this pluggin: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/ . It has everything you asked.

Answer (score 0):

This looks really good and polished - http://gristmill.github.com/jquery-popbox/index.html